# PHP how do I make a successful login redirect to a page that is otherwise inaccessible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making a website for a local sportsclub and I want to make an admin page to edit things like planned activities etc. The plan is to have a url (www.example.com/login) where the admin has to login. After a successful login the admin should be redirected to a new page (www.example.com/dashboard). I have this login form in php but the problem is that you can still access the dashboard without being logged in by just typing the URL. This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
if($user=="admin" && $pass=="admin"){
  echo("username and password matched")
}else{echo("error! please enter correct credentials");}

}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I'm missing and what I don't know how to do is to make the form redirect to the dashboard after a successful login and to make the dashboard page forbidden if you're not logged in.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Set a session variable when you login. All pages that require a login then need to check whether the variable is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session_start()` and `$_SESSION` global variable.

After successful login set a value there:

```php
$_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;
```

and in the code of your pages check if the variable is set:

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) || $_SESSION['signed_in'] !== true) {
   header('Location: /your_login_page.php');
   exit();
}
```